# 18.04.4 Cannot turn on remote desktop sharing

Tags: 18.04, vnc, sharing

I have installed Ubuntu with the minimum setup instead of the normal install. I am trying to connect into Ubuntu but Sharing will not stay on. (I would like to use `vnc`)

[image: Settings - Sharing]

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i solved it , just follow my steps :

**Option 1 :**

**1.** Just type this command in your terminal : `sudo apt install vino` and enter your Password.

[image]

**2.** Reboot your machine.

**3.** It's worked now.

[image]

**Option2 :**

**1.** Install dconf Editor `sudo apt install dconf-editor`

**2.** Open it and go to `/org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/`

[image]

**3.** Look for `require-encryption` , `custom value = false`. Then click on `Apply`.

[image]

**4.** Open terminal and type : `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server --sm-disable start`

**5.** See `settings --> sharing` again.

Hope that helps you to solve your issue, Good luck.

Comment: still not working but vino-server crashed